# Python: Replacing multiple specific words from a list with re.sub

Tags: python, regex, list, replace

I have the following string and list 'changewords'. I would like to replace the '{word from list} \n' with '{word from list}:' I don't want to replace all instances of '\n'.

```py
string = "Foo \n value of something \n Bar \n Another value \n"
changewords = ["Foo", "Bar"]
```

Desired Output:

```py
'Foo: value of something \n Bar: Another value \n'
```

I have tried the following

```py
for i in changewords:
    tem = re.sub(f'{i} \n', f'{i}:', string)
tem
Output: 'Foo \n value of something \n Bar: Another value \n'
```

and

```py
changewords2 = '|'.join(changewords)
tem = re.sub(f'{changewords2} \n', f'{changewords2}:', string)
tem
Output: 'Foo|Bar: \n value of something \n Foo|Bar: Another value \n'
```

How can I get my desired output?

Comment: might want to check out the other answers too @RohanGupta. Some examples show more what the intent of reg expr's can do. Otherwise, might as well just use `"".replace()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using replacement string:**

A slightly more elegant way of doing it. This one-liner:

```
re.sub(rf"({'|'.join(changewords)}) \n", r"\1:", string, flags=re.I)
```

demo:

```
>>> string = "Foo \n value of something \n Bar \n Another value \n"
>>> changewords = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'qux']
>>> 
>>> re.sub(rf"({'|'.join(changewords)}) \n", r"\1:", string, flags=re.I)
'Foo: value of something \n Bar: Another value \n'
>>>
```

You can specify case insensitive matching with the `flags` option. And the replacement string can be modified to have anything around `\1` needed like colons or commas.

Worth noting, you can put more than one specifier on strings in Python. For instance you can have both `r` and `f` like, `rf"my raw formatted string"` - the order of specifiers isn't important.

Within the expression in `re.sub(expr, repl, string)`, you can specify groups. Groups are made by placing parenthesis `()` around text.

Groups can then be referenced in the replacement string, `repl`, by using a backslash and the number of its occurrence - the first group is referred to by `\1`.

The `re.sub()` function, `re.sub(rf"(A|B|C) \n", r"\1: ")`, associates `\1` within the replacement string with the first group `(A|B|C)` within the expression argument.

**Using replacement function:**

Suppose you want to replace words in the target string with other words from a dictionary. For instance you want 'Bar' to be replaced with 'Hank' and 'Foo' with 'Bernard'. This can be done using a replacement function instead of replacement string:

```
>>> repl_dict = {'Foo':'Bernard', 'Bar':'Hank'}
>>> 
>>> expr = rf"({'|'.join(repl_dict.keys())}) \n"   # Becomes '(Foo|Bar) \\n'
>>>
>>> func = lambda mo: f"{repl_dict[mo.group(1)]}:"
>>> 
>>> re.sub(expr, func, string, flags=re.I)
'Bernard: value of something \n Hank: Another value \n'
>>>
```

This could be another one-liner, but I broke it up for clarity...

What the lambda function does is take the match object, `mo` passed to it, then extract the first group's text. The first group in the reg expr is the text encompassed by `()`, which would be like `(A|B|C)`.

The replacement function references this first group using, `mo.group(1)`; similarly, the replacement string referenced it by, `\1` in the previous example.

Then the repl function does the lookup in the dict and returns the final replacement string for the match.

Comment: is it possible to get ':' after the words?

Comment: You want to have a colon after the replacement?

Comment: yes. The output should look like "Foo: Value of something \n Bar: Another Value \n"

Comment: 4th argument of `re.sub` is `count` and 5th is `flags`

Comment: A subtle difference between `for` loop and this approach is that for ignore case match it will output `Foo: value of something` (since original text has `Foo`) whereas loop with show `foo: value of something` `foo` is from replacement array.

Comment: I added another example of a more advanced way to do replacements with `re.sub()` @RohanGupta

Answer (score 2):

You may use this code:

```
import re

string = "Foo \n value of something \n Bar \n Another value \n"
changewords = ["foo", "Bar"]

tem = string
for i in changewords:
    tem = re.sub(f'(?i){i} \n', f'{i}:', tem)
print( tem )
```

**Output:**

```
foo: value of something
 Bar: Another value
```

Note `tem = string` to initialize `tem` value and then inside the `for` loop use `re.sub` on `tem` with assigning back result to `tem` itself.

Use of `(?i)` is for ignore case matching.

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/AVfOHR)

Answer (score 0):

You could very well not use regex at all, and my first approach would be to use the builtin string function `.replace()`, to make it look something like:

```py
string = "Foo \n value of something \n Bar \n Another value \n"
changewords = ["Foo", "Bar"]

for word in changewords:
   to_replace = "{0} \n".format(word)
   replacement = "{0}:".format(word)
   string = string.replace(to_replace, replacement)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Definitely helped! However, I also wanted to use re.IGNORECASE within my re.sub function. Is it possible to use IGNORECASE with the .replace() funtion?