# Is there a standard way of dealing with regular expressions when a prefix is present for multiple instances?

Tags: python, regex, string

For instance:

There are multiple instances in a column of my dataframe (that happens to be a nested JSON) in which there is something like 'prefix("stuff i want"),'.

How do I replace 'prefix("stuff i want"),' with "stuff i want"?

Comment: As stated, the variables are strings. I updated the question to reflect this more clearly.

Comment: So the desired result is `x = '"hello"'`?

Comment: Are the paranthesis always at the end?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes. There is a comma included as well. The desired result is x = '"hello",'.

Comment: @Tomerikoo There is actually a comma always at the end. I updated the question to include that.

Comment: Can there be parens in there, such as `'prefix("hello (there)")'`?

Comment: @tdelaney No, never.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis

Comment: @seeaemearohin, check out the bottom of my answer for an answer to "how do I replace... with stuff I want"

Comment: @seeaemearohin also check out my answer for a more elaborate way to replace matching text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514155/7915759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using grouping**

*The question was updated to be more specific after I put together what's immediately below - for a more specific answer, you can scroll down to **referencing groups** where I have examples on how to do replacements.*

Using groups to single out matching text in a target string:

```
>>> re.findall(r"prefix\((.*?)\)", 'prefix("hello")')[0]
'"hello"'
```

or more generally to capture anything in parenthesis:

```
re.findall(r"\((.*?)\)", 'prefix("hello")')[0]
'"hello"'
```

**demo**

```
>>> target = """
... x = 'prefix("hello"),'
... y = 'prefix("hi"),'
... z = 'prefix("hey"),'
... """
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r"prefix\((.*?)\)", target)
['"hello"', '"hi"', '"hey"']
>>>
```

I believe the feature of regular expressions that would benefit you would be "groups".

When you use unescaped parenthesis `(.....)` around text in your regexpr you create a matching group. This is a powerful way to extract bits and pieces from the target text.

**reference**
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

> (...) Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses,
>   and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group
>   can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched
>   later in the string with the \number special sequence, described
>   below. To match the literals '(' or ')', use ( or ), or enclose them
>   inside a character class: [(], [)].

**referencing groups**

Also, you can reference your matching groups using a backslash and a number: `\1` would be the first match group. This is useful for operations like `re.sub()`

```
>>> print(re.sub(r"prefix\((.*?)\)", r"prefix(   && \1 &&   )", target))

x = 'prefix(   && "hello" &&   ),'
y = 'prefix(   && "hi" &&   ),'
z = 'prefix(   && "hey" &&   ),'

>>>
```

You can do things like above where I put `&&` around the group to make it stand out.

More along the lines of answering the exact question, we can extract the text we need and dispense with 'prefix' and other text we don't need:

```
>>> print(re.sub(r"'prefix\((.*?)\),'", r"\1", target))

x = "hello"
y = "hi"
z = "hey"

>>>
```

(assuming you want to keep the double quotes in the output, and lose the tick quotes and commas)

*For more elaborate match replacement operations, you can check out my other post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514155/7915759.  In that example I show how to match text from a list of words, and how to replace matches with text from a dictionary.*

**positive lookbehind/ahead assertion**

In most cases lookahead/behind isn't needed, but they are also an option. They offer a way to specify preceding/subsequent text without grouping. As in other posts to the question, the syntax is `(?<=...)` for lookbehind, and `(?=...)` for lookahead.

These subexpressions can complicate the overall expression and make it more difficult to read. Maybe not always, but they should be used sparingly in my opinion.

The question of whether to use them or not if there's a way to do it without them is: does it make your code easier to read?  Whichever way is easier to grok for you and other developers is the one you should go with.

Here's an example using lookahead/behind assertions that does the same thing as the previous example. Which is easier to comprehend - you can decide:

```
>>> print(re.sub(r"(?<=prefix\()(.*?)(?=\))", r"   && \1 &&   ", target))

x = 'prefix(   && "hello" &&   ),'
y = 'prefix(   && "hi" &&   ),'
z = 'prefix(   && "hey" &&   ),'
```

In the particular case of the question, using these assertions would lose the `prefix...` text from the match and you wouldn't be able to remove it from the `re.sub()` output. So in this case, they wouldn't work.

Comment: This is not what I would consider a general response. hello could be anything.

Comment: @seeaemearohin you are probably new to regex... where it says `hello` is the actual string to be searched... the pattern is before that `"\((.*?)\)"`

Answer (score 1):

Make the use of lookarounds. The regex for this would be:

```
regex = r'(?<=prefix\()".*"(?=\))'
re.findall(regex, your_string)
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/0ZEXnN/2/

Comment: This is probably what the OP wants. Can you please put that within r"" quotes?

Comment: @Predicate. Todd is right. This is closer to what I want. Is it possible to do something like re.replace(regex, "hello") where "hello" is, in general, anything?

Comment: @seeaemearohin You mean `re.sub`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, re.sub. How would that work? I think that would be the solution.

Comment: This can also be achieved without lookahead or lookback just using regular parenthesis to group matching text @seeaemearohin

Comment: @Tomerikoo Something like re.sub(regex, .*) where .* is whatever is between the parentheses - in this case being "hello".

Comment: @seeaemearohin And dont forget to upvote and accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works

```
x = 'prefix("hello")'
y = 'prefix("hi")'
z = 'prefix("hey")'

import re
for test in (x,y,z):
    print(test, re.match(r".*?\(([^\)]*)", test).group(1))
```

result

```
prefix("hello") "hello"
prefix("hi") "hi"
prefix("hey") "hey"
```